# jQuery UI Sliders hops when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, slider

I'm using **Jquery UI slider** to create two different slide effect, one [horizontal](http://bit.ly/dVLPfc) and other [vertical](http://bit.ly/g5rflP).

But there is an unique problem with both of them which is bugging me and my client, and I don't seem to be able to find a solution. This is a headache and a bummer after all the work I have been but into these modules.

I'm sure that I'm not the only one having this problem, but don't seem to find any solutions which fit my problem online

You can see both modules here

http://bit.ly/dVLPfc

http://bit.ly/g5rflP

The slider it self uses percentage for its position "left:0%", if you click on slider it hops about 5-7%. So it seems  a bit unstable. What I want is for the slider to use the amount of percentage it is set on when I click it and than change only if I move the mouse. I have tried to stick the position into a value and throw it in when I click on the slider, but the **UI slider plugin** over-writes it.

The slider does not always follow the cursors speed, in the [vertical version](http://bit.ly/g5rflP) you can see it moves out of the cursors spot under some circumstances.

Let me know what you think, hopefully you can help me get on the right track.

Comment: Is that supposed to be "bounce", like a rubber ball?

Comment: no, it move correctly with the slider, just moves unnecessarily when clicked

Comment: Well there's no word "bounch"; maybe "bunch", as in "gather" or "clump together"?

Comment: sorry, did not see that, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your slider handle margins appear to be wrong for the size of your custom-styled slider handles.

Your left or top margins need to be half the length or height of the scroll handle.

For your first module, because the length of your horizontal slider handle is 60px, you need to change the slider handle **margin-left** to -30px in dagskra.css.

```
#dagskra .slider div a {
    background: url("../images/dagskra/slider/slider.png") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.5em;
    width: 60px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

For your second module, because the height of the vertical slider handle is 50px, you need to change the slider handle **margin-top** to -25px in dagatal.css.

```
.ui-slider-handle {
    background: url("../images/dagatal/scroll/slider.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -4px;
    width: 16px;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I have been looking at this for weeks. Is this something you just figured out ore is this standard practise for custom slider styling (than I then missed)? :)

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @einar I looked at the custom Slider style example at http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll and noticed that the handle is manually styled with a margin exactly half the width of the handle.  If you remove that margin, then the handle has the exact same problem you were having.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Some times you need fresh eyes on things to understand the problem :)